# How to share constants between client and server in Express, React, Webpack, SSR app

Tags: javascript, express, webpack

How do I share common constants between the client and the server when doing a universal, server side rendered Javascript web app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Webpack's [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#defineplugin)

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    PRODUCTION: JSON.stringify(true),
    VERSION: JSON.stringify("5fa3b9"),
})
```

Note that this plugin will inject these values into the page literally. Meaning if you do something like this:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({ FOO: "BAR" });
```

Then Webpack will literally insert:

```
var FOO = BAR;
```

Which will error, because the bare string `BAR` looks like a variable that doesn't exist. That's why the example shows most things wrapped in JSON.stringify, which returns quoted values, so inserting

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({ FOO: JSON.stringify("BAR") });
```

Will correctly insert:

```
var FOO = "BAR";
```

Yes, this is terrible design. Webpack's API is a minefield.

Comment: Does this work if I want to share common functions as well?

Comment: No. Just require those like any normal javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can set them as environment variables - you can access them without problems on backend side and you can inject them into client js files using `webpack.DefinePlugin`

Answer (score 0):

This is a very vague question, but you can use define plugin:

Use Define Plugin in your webpack config.

```
   plugins: [new webpack.DefinePlugin({__SERVER_RENDERING__: false})]
```